# How would sex chromosome inheritance work in a tetraploid trioecious species with the ZW sex determination system?

Tags: hard-science, flora, genetics, reproduction, sex

I imagined a trioecious angiosperm species descended from common cocoa trees (*Theobroma cacao*). Trioecious = three sexes (male, female, and simultaneous hermaphrodite).

They use the ZW sex-determination system (like *Amborella trichopoda*, Virginian strawberries, pistachios, *Schistosoma*, woodlice, lepidopterans, amphioxi, American eels, tilapias, giant salamanders, sirens, axolotls, cane toads, lacertids, anguimorphs, and birds). ZW = the default state is to develop as male, and the mother is the parent responsible for determining the sex of the offspring. In other words, male is the homogametic sex, and female is the heterogametic sex. When a female of a species that uses the ZW sex-determination system reproduces asexually (google parthenogenesis), they only have sons rather than daughters (because at least a Z chromosome is necessary to live, and having two W chromosomes or just one is a lethal condition).

However, this species is tetraploid rather than diploid.

So, I wonder how sex chromosome inheritance would be in a trioecious species that uses the ZW sex-determination system.

Comment: I found a [website](https://sitn.hms.harvard.edu/flash/2016/im-xy-know-sex-determination-systems-101/) you might be interested in, scroll down to the middle section for zw...

Comment: For those readers who might be confused: (1) *Theobroma cacao* is monoecious, that is, it has perfect flowers, not dioecious or trioecious. (2) *T. cacao* is diploid (2 *n* = 10), not tetraploid. (3) Whatever the mysterious trees in the question are, they are definitely not *T. cacao*.

Comment: Data conflict detected. If ZW is a female, and it reproduces asexually, it cannot produce only males, as offspring would be ZW instead of ZZ.

Answer (score 1):

The article [Preferential Pairing of Sex Chromosomes in the Tetraploid Silkworms (Bombyx Mori)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1601-5223.1994.00073.x) shows that in silkworms that have been induced to be tetraploid (they are normally diploid), there are a number of possible pairings of the Z and W sex chromosomes, but that like-with-like pairing is much more common:

> In the oocytes  of  the  silkworm, Bombyx mori, only the sex chromosome bivalent (ZW) can be identified among the 28 bivalents, when we use the  females of the sex-limited yellow cocoon (Sy) strain, in which the W carries a  long fragment of the  second chromosome. Autotetraploid  silkwonns were induced from Sy females,  in order to investigate  whether  preferential  pairing  between Z and Z as well as W and W occurs in  the  4n  oocytes.  Two  types  of  pairing patterns, (ZZ + WW) and (ZW + ZW), were  observed in the oocytes, and the ratio of  the  pairing patterns, (ZZ + WW): (ZW + ZW), was 3421 in  Sy4n (Sy9 x Sy$), while 16:2 in  Syr4n (Sy9 x re93). Sex chromosome formulae of  the  eggs formed by the tetraploid can he confirmed  when tetraploid females are crossed  with  sch  males  (sex-linked  chocolate larva). The triploid offspring from Syr4n  females mated  with  sch males,  showed ZW gametes and ZZ gemetes produced in a 22:l  ratio, which coincides  with  the ratio calculated from the  pairing pattern  ratio, 16:2. The results indicated  preferential  pairing of Z with Z and of W with W in tetraploid oocytes.

While this study was performed in insects rather than trees, the biology of cellular division and gamete production is common across the animal and plant kingdoms, and we could expect similar results in a plant species.

Since we don't know how the OP's proposed hermaphroditic sex occurs in this tetraploid species, it would be up to the OP to determine how a non-standard mixture of Z and W chromosomes would result in this condition.  However, one possibility is detailed below:

In the (diploid) [ZW sex-determination system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZW_sex-determination_system), males possess two Z chromosomes, while females possess a Z and a W chromosome.  Like the XY chromosome system, the ZW system also results in offspring being 50% male and 50% female.  So far, there is no clear way to have trioecy and a hermaphrodite sex.

However, if we have tetraploidy (having four copies of the genome, and not just two as in diploidy), we no longer have the possibility of only ZZ or ZW, we have ZZZZ, ZZZW, ZZWW and ZWWW, with WWWW being lethal.

If we consider that ZZZZ is by necessity male, the presence of one or more W-chromosomes should make the offspring female or hermaphrodite.  Since the study above shows that in meiosis, like pairs with like much more often than like with unlike (i.e. ZZ or WW occurs much more frequently than ZW), we can expect the majority of offspring to be ZZZZ or ZZWW.

I am arbitrarily stating the frequency of a ZW paring in meiosis where a ZZ or WW pairing is possible to be 1%, though it need not be exactly that frequency:

`ZZZZ x ZZWW -> 49% ZZZZ, 49% ZZWW, 2% ZZZW`

If we were to say that ZZZW led to hermaphroditic offspring, this would work.  If we cross a hermaphrodite with a male or hermaphrodite respectively, we would get:

`ZZZW x ZZZZ -> 50% ZZZZ, 50% ZZZW`

i.e. 50% males, 50% hermaphrodite.

`ZZZW x ZZZW -> 25% ZZZZ, 50% ZZZW, 25% ZZWW`

i.e. 25% males, 50% hermaphrodite, 25% females.

However, if we cross a hermaphrodite with a female, we get:

`ZZZW x ZZWW -> 24% ZZZZ, 24% ZZWW, 24% ZWZZ, 24% ZWWW, 2% ZZZW, 2% ZWZW`

`-> 24% ZZZZ, 26% ZZWW, 26% ZZZW, 24% ZWWW.`

That is, *less* than a quarter Males, *more* than a quarter females, *more* than a quarter hermaphrodites, and *less* than a quarter... something else, ZWWW.

What is this ZWWW genotype?  Since ZZZZ is male, ZZZW is hermaphrodite and ZZWW is female, is ZWWW some sort of *super*-female?

We have two options.  The simplest is to say that ZWWW is lethal, so crosses between hermaphrodites and females are less fertile.  The alternative is that we have *another* set of crosses, super-female with the other sexes:

`ZWWW x ZZZZ -> 50% ZZZW, 50% ZZWW`

i.e. 50% hermaphrodite, 50% female.

`ZWWW x ZZZW -> 25% ZWZZ, 25% ZWZW, 25% WWZZ, 25% WWZW`

`-> 25% ZZZW, 50% ZZWW, 25% ZWWW`

i.e. 25% hermaphrodite, 50% Female, 25% super-female.

However ZWWW super-female x ZZWW female is not possible.

So, it is possible to have trioecy *if* the genetic combinations ZZZZ are male, ZZZW are hermaphrodite, ZZWW are female and ZWWW is lethal.

Alternatively, we would have *quadr*oecy... unless ZZWW females and ZWWW super-females were phenotypically identical, in which case the species would *appear* trioecious.

Comment: Gamete production is **not** homologous in plants and animals. Plants and animals have acquired sexual reproduction separately. Their most recent common ancestor did not reproduce sexually.

Comment: @AlexP from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis, "Meiosis occurs in all sexually-reproducing single-celled and multicellular organisms (which are all eukaryotes), including animals, plants and fungi."

Comment: Duh, if they produce gametes then they *must* have a some form of a halving cell division. (The Greek word *meiōsis* means simply "diminution".) (In animals, the meiotic division produces gametes. Not so in plants, where the meiotic division produces haploid spores, which then undergo few or many cell divisions depending on what kind of plant we are speaking about, and only afterwards the haploid gametophyte produces gametes by ordinary mitotic cell division.)

Comment: Why are we down voting this? The goal is to help the OP rationalize a worldbuilding rule... not write a textbook on the science of the OP's world (no matter the [tag:hard-science] tag). Even if the answer isn't 100% perfect science here on Earth, does it not answer the OP's question?